# Opencart 3.0.3.3 telephone_not_required (vqmod)

Tags: website

I have successfully installed vqmod and placed the xml of the mod in /vqmod/xml.

In the admin page, under extensions -> modifications I refresh and clear, but no plugin shows up.

Actually I only want to disable the telephone required field in the store properties because the owner hasn't gotten a business phone number.

What else can I try?

This is the plugin: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=36453&filter_category_id=21&filter_download_id=55&sort=date_added

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: go to design -> theme editor -> common -> header.twig

Find and delete:

```
<li><a href="{{ contact }}"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">{{ telephone }}</span></li>
```

Click save and refresh your store page. It should now not show the telephone number so a dummy one can be entered instead. Use the same approach for every other page that shows the phone number...